# jQuery Simple Collapsible Div?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am looking for the proper, simple, small code to do the following things:

- Click on Element with Class Applied to it.
- DIV.CLASS - Which expands and shows hidden content. (slideDown - Toggle)
- DIV.CLASS - Which collapses and hides the previously show content. (slideUp - Toggle)

```html
<div class="sitesection">
    <p class="expand-one"><a href="#">Click Here To Display The Content</a> <img src="images/arrow.png" width="5" height="7" /></p>
    <p class="content-one">This is the content that was hidden before, but now is... Well, visible!"</p>
</div>
```

So to be vague and easy, I need to know how to get a DIV CLASS to become hidden and visible once an element on the same page has a CLASS applied to it, in which would activate and deactivate the HIDDEN and or VISIBLE HTML Content. And I need it to be hidden by default.

I have looked all over the internet and have only found very complex scripts, but nothing simple. I have found Simple Accordians... But those never close, they just open another one.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

```
$('.expand-one').click(function(){
    $('.content-one').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Q4PUw/2/

Comment: Is it me or does it load faster using "slideToggle" then using .accordion ?

Answer (score 9):

I was looking at this and wanted a collapsible div that was already styled for me. Then I realized what I wanted was a single pane jquery-ui accordion.

```
<div id="collapse">
   <h3>Collapse and Expand</h3>
   <div>Content</div>
</div>
<script>
$( "#collapse" ).accordion({
    collapsible: true,
    active: false
});
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MB4ch/1/

Comment: Note, this is jQueryUI, not plain jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to do this with multiple divs, each with their own trigger. Building on AlienWebguy's answer above:

HTML

```
<div>
    <p class="expand" id="expand-1">more 1...</p>
</div>
<div class="expandable" id="expandable-1">
    <p>1. This is the content that was hidden before, but now is... Well, visible!"</p>
</div>
<div>
    <p class="expand" id="expand-2">more 2...</p>
</div>
<div class="expandable" id="expandable-2">
    <p>2. This is the content that was hidden before, but now is... Well, visible!"</p>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$('.expand').click(function(){
    target_num = $(this).attr('id').split('-')[1];
    content_id = '#expandable-'.concat(target_num);
    $(content_id).slideToggle('fast');
});
```

CSS

```
.expand {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.expandable {
    display:none;
}
div {
    margin: 10px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Q4PUw/3767/

Comment: Precisely the type of simple solution I was looking for. +1

Comment: actually, this script executes once per .expandable item on my page for some reason... Any idea why this would happen?

Answer (score 0):

Bad idea to use accordion. 
Better is to create your own collapsible block.

Example:

```
function InitSpoilBlock(idClicked)
    {
        $(idClicked).on('click', function(e){
            var textArray = ['blind','slide'];//here you can add other effects

            var randomEffect = textArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*textArray.length)];

            $(e.target).parent().children(".HiderPanel").toggle(randomEffect);
        });
    }
```

so when you write such html:

```
<div class="HiderContainer">
    <a href="#" class="Hider">More</a>
    <div class="HiderPanel">
        Spoiled block of html
    </div>
</div>
```

and after page load you will call

```
InitSpoilBlock('.Hider');
```

all blocks will be possible to collapse and hide with random animation. Or you can use one exact animation also.