# Is there a better way to set up the gallery so the collapse div does not move other elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As you can see [here (JSFiddle)](http://www.jsfiddle.net/kwillisbws/2pvxR/) I have some boxes. When you click the first box you can see what the collapse div does. I want the div to collapse under the image but not to move the other boxes to its right.

I am assuming there is a better way of laying out the gallery for this to happen.

Comment: Can you elaborate more how you want this to work? Do you want all 3 'boxes' to be vertically stacked, with the middle one being hidden by the third one when you click the first one?

Comment: on the JSFiddle link you can see two boxes one red and one blue. Id like for both of them to stay in there positions and for the collapse div to just appear under the blue box

Comment: The positions of the boxes changes depending on the width of my browser. At low widths, they're stacked. At high widths, they appear next to one another. Which do you want?

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to make this work as you want by using that plugin. The reason it does that is not based on any styling fault of yours; it's inherent in the Javascript. So you have two options:

1. Edit the source code to fix your issue (probably not worth it)
2. Make your own script, which wouldn't be too hard I'm sure.
3. Find a new script. [Pretty simple ones just might work for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495257/jquery-simple-collapsible-div)

However, there are a few other things I noted. Firstly, if you open a `ul`, any immediate children of it must be an `li` or your html won't be valid. So, to be explicit, your html should always take the following form:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href=""></a></li>
  <li><div></div></li>
  <li>...</li>
<ul>
```

And you can clean up your CSS quite a bit. [Take a look!](http://jsfiddle.net/wQB3K/)